# std::map custom key non-uniqueness problem

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, key

Couldn't find an answer on Google..

When I use std::string the following works fine.

```
map <fxString, int> test;
test.insert(pair <fxString, int> ("Bla", 1));
test.insert(pair <fxString, int> ("Bla", 2));
test.insert(pair <fxString, int> ("Bla", 3));
cout << fxInt2String(test["Bla"]) << endl;
```

Which should output 1, but instead outputs 0

When I iterate through the map every key value pair is there, sitting right next to each other mocking me.

fxString defines the following operators:
operator >
operator <
operator ==
operator !=

And more, and I tested them..

Grom.

Comment: What is `fxString` and `fxInt2String`?

Comment: what does your `<` operator look like?

Comment: `operator<` should return false for objects that are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "When I iterate through the map **every**
>   key value pair is there"

Well, something is wrong with your `fxString::operator<` then, because the `insert` member function should have no effect if the key is already present. Are you sure this operator models a [strict weak ordering](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/) ?

Assuming that the operator is broken, `test["Bla"]` has the effect of adding yet another element in the map with a default value of 0.

Comment: +1 - The `operator<` is almost certainly the cause of both problems.  The reason the map is inserting each new record is that it searches for 'Bla', and can't find it.  Likewise in retrieval, it can't find 'Bla', and returns a default value (adding in a new pair at the same time.)

Comment: @Eclipse: right, answer edited to explain why a 0 is displayed

Comment: I implemented a very simple quick check for operator < but it would sometimes return true even though the two strings are the same. Thanks mate! =)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine (as you have noted)

```
map <string, int> test;
test.insert(pair <string, int> ("Bla", 1));
test.insert(pair <string, int> ("Bla", 2));
test.insert(pair <string, int> ("Bla", 3));
cout << test["Bla"] << endl;
```

So there must be either problem with your `fxInt2String` function or with your operator overloads.

To receive further help you should provide us with code for the functions in question.

Comment: I have, of course, read it. I have just provided an example which works (and the author is aware of that). So the answer itself is "So there must be either problem with your fxInt2String function or with your operator overloads." Without further code, there is not much we can do.

Comment: Edited for your satisfaction anyway :P